# Connect via PHP to SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, php, database, connection, sql-server-2012

My problem has a couple things:

- I got a website constructed in joomla, hosted on linux server (that means that sqlsrv doesn't work because it's made for windows only, and the host administrator already informed me that they can't install any php extension).
- I got a C# program, and my database is hosted on Amazon (SQL Server 2012).

To resume, i need to connect my website to my SQL database program to show data, and modify it, etc etc, on web.

So, if you guys have any ideia how can i make it, i really appreciate that.

Best regards,
Hélder Lopes

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install the php module :
source : [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
source : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

If there is no way, move your database to your website's hosting (converting db to mysql), and make your C# program use mysql and point it to the website database.
good luck.

Comment: Your first recomendation is a php extension right? I know it works, but like i said host administrator doesn't allow to install any php extension, to avoid server problems. Your second recomendation, can you please explain me how this is done?It needs a specific program to convert Sql server to mysql? And after converting database, c# program works fine with a mysql database to insert and update data?Do you know any site with a tutorial to do that?

Comment: you can convert your database using this : http://dbconvert.com/convert-mssql-to-mysql-pro.php

but you have to make several changes in your program C#, If you're using a datalayer, you will have to go through each class and change the query to fit mysql syntax, and then use MYSQL driver connection.
Let me know if it doesn't make sense.